# Why are my bash script's arguments causing an error?

Tags: 12.10, command-line, scripts

In order to make uploading the code to github easily, I created a sh script

```
#commit.sh
git add .
git commit -m $1
git push origin master
```

But when I run it by saying `./commit.sh "comment1 comment2 comment3"` , I get the error of:

```
error: pathspec 'comment2' did not match any file(s) known to git.
error: pathspec 'comment3' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

What's wrong and how do I make it work?

Comment: $2 is comment2, $3 is comment3

Comment: how do I make it work?

Comment: Removed my comment. Timo Kluck answer works, just checked it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Always quote your variables! Change it to

```
git commit -m "$1"
```

and then

```
./commit.sh "comment1 comment2 comment3"
```

will work.

Answer (score 3):

You could combine several commands in one line.

```
git add . && git commit -m "Your commit message" && git push origin master
```

which is a nice line to use as a command:

```
gitpush()
{
git add . && git commit -m "$1" && git push origin master
}
```

If you place that command in your `.bash_aliases` file, you can use it as follows:

```
gitpush "finally fixed that long-standing bug"
```

This command will work when every step of it works.

Comment: I must note that `git commit -a` is not the same as `git add . && git commit`, as `git add .` doesn't remove files from the index, although `git commit -a` will stage all changes before commit.

Comment: how do I use gitpush()? Where do I create it and how do I call it?

Comment: @Dan You are right, let me stick to expressing everything.

Comment: Hi Alex, I have edited the answer to say you should put in, for instance, in .bash_aliases file. Check http://www.howtogeek.com/73768/how-to-use-aliases-to-customize-ubuntu-commands/ If needed, log out and back in.

Comment: @Private You still need to remove the `a` option from `git commit` so it becomes the same as the OP's request ;)